# Passing a parameter to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I need to create a Javascript function (using a loop) that receives a value as a parameter from a function call in HTML and in response passes back the image of the back of a playing card however many times the value of the parameter is.

For example, if I pass the value 5 to the function, I should get back 5 images of the back of the card from the function displayed on the HTML page inside an existing table.

Here is what I have so far. Can someone please point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong (Thank you in advance for any help).

**JS**

```
function showCards(numcards) { 
  var data = ""; 
  while (numcards < 5) {
    data += "<td><img src="http://www.college1.com/images/cards/gbCard52.gif" NAME="card0"></td>";
    numcards +=;
  }
  document.writeln(data);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border=0 style='margin:auto'>
  <tr> 
   <td>
     <form>
       <input type="BUTTON" onClick="Javascript:alert('Dummy Link')" value="Deal > > >">
     </form>
   </td> 
   <script type="text/javascript">showCards(5)</script>   
   <td>
     <form>
       <input type="BUTTON" onClick="Javascript:alert('Dummy Link')" value="< < < Hit Me">
     </form>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work in this code? Behavior you get vs behavior you want. Your function doesn't give anything 'back' by the way. It just writes to the document.

Comment: `"<td><img src="` terminates the string, anything after that is an obvious syntax error, just look at the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mainly syntax errors in your code.

1. Either escape the double quote inside a string (ie. `"\""`) or use single quotes to declare your string.
2. You were trying to increment `numcards` using a wrong syntax. The correct syntax is `numcards++`.
3. But that's not what you want, you want to decrement it to 0 (ie. `numcard--`) to get your number of cards or count up to `numcards` using a `for loop` for example.

```js
function showCards(numcards) {
  var data = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numcards; i++) {
    data += '<td><img src="http://www.college1.com/images/cards/gbCard52.gif" NAME="card0"></td>';
  }
  
  document.writeln(data);
}

showCards(5);
```

```html
<table border=0 style='margin:auto'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form><input type="BUTTON" onClick="Javascript:alert('Dummy Link')" value="Deal > > >"></form>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form><input type="BUTTON" onClick="Javascript:alert('Dummy Link')" value="< < < Hit Me"></form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// where you want to append images tag
var table = document.querySelector('tbody');

// you can call this method on click event
function show(elem , param) {
  var i = 0;
  var data = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = "";
  while (param != i) {
    
    td += "<td><img src='http://www.college1.com/images/cards/gbCard52.gif' NAME='card"+i+"'></td>";
    i++; 
  }
  data.innerHTML = td;
  // append html tr node 
  elem.appendChild(data);
}
// calling when the script is loaded
show(table, 5);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```